# ¿Como obtener la cancelación de una suscripción en mi IPN?

Tags: php, paypal

Tengo un inconveniente porque cuando trato de poder obtener una notificación de cancelación por parte del usuario o directamente por Paypal al no tener fondos el cliente. Pero tengo el detalle que este IPN se ejecuta más de una vez, es decir, yo agregue una función de notificación por email pero el IPN es llamado más de una vez es decir el usuario cancela y se envían 2 notificaciones o si el usuario renueva la suscripción igual le llegan 2 de suspensión.

**Código completo**

```
    <?php

include_once 'func_sql/funcSQL.php';
include_once 'lib/phpmailer/libemail.php';

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();

$libemail = new LibEmail();

foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

$getplan_id=$_REQUEST['id_plan'];
$usuario_id=$_REQUEST['id_usuario'];
// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {



    // assign posted variables to local variables
    /*$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];*/
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];

    /*$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];*/
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];



    $SQL = new SQL;

    $plan_anterior = $SQL->obtener_usuario_plan($usuario_id);

    $usuplan_tel_iCassy = $SQL->obtener_numero_icassy();



    $usuario = $SQL ->obtener_usuario ($usuario_id);

    $plan = $SQL->obtener_plan ($getplan_id);

    //$fecha_fin = $_POST['next_payment_date'];

    $clave = generateIcassyKey($getplan_id);

    /*if(!empty($plan_anterior)){
        $usuplan_tel_iCassy = $plan_anterior['usuplan_iCassy_tel'];
        $clave = $plan_anterior['usuplan_iCassy_Clave'];
    }*/

    if(!empty($txn_id)){


            $plan_2 = $SQL->obtener_plan_webhook($usuario_id);
            $asut = 'contratación';
            $asut2 = 'Contratación';

            if($plan_2 !== 'nulo'){
                $clave = $plan_2['usuplan_iCassy_Clave'];
                $usuplan_tel_iCassy = $plan_2['usuplan_iCassy_tel'];
                $asut = 'recontratación';
                $asut2 = 'Recontratación';
            }

            $SQL->registrar_plan($usuario_id, $getplan_id, $plan['plan_nombre'], date("Y-m-d"), 
                    date("Y-m-d")/*fechafin*/, $payer_email, $plan['plan_precio'], $txn_id, 
                    date("Y-m-d"), $clave, $usuplan_tel_iCassy,$usuario['usuario_telf'], 1);

            $SQL->crear_historico($usuario_id, $getplan_id, $plan['plan_nombre'], date("Y-m-d"), 
                    date("Y-m-d")/*fechafin*/, $payer_email, $plan['plan_precio'], $txn_id, 
                    'Activo', date("Y-m-d"), $clave, $usuplan_tel_iCassy ,$usuario['usuario_telf']);

            $texto = "
                    Sr.(a) ".$usuario['usuario_nombre'].", El proceso de $asut de su Plan se produjo de manera exitosa.
                    <br><br>
                    Sus datos asignados:
                    <br>Teléfono iCassy Asignado: ".$usuplan_tel_iCassy."
                    <br>Clave iCassy Asignada: ".$clave."
                    ";
                    $asunto = "$asut2 de Plan - ICASSY";

                    $libemail->enviarcorreo($usuario['usuario_email'], $asunto, $texto);

                    $SQL->actualizar_status_usuario_2($usuario_id, 'activo');


    }
    // <---- HERE you can do your INSERT to the database

    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // log for manual investigation

    }

    $subcr_id = $_POST['subcr_id'];

    if(!empty($subcr_id)){
            $type = $_POST['txn_type'];


    if($type === 'subscr_cancel' ){

                $SQL->registrar_plan($usuario_id, $getplan_id, $plan['plan_nombre'], date("Y-m-d"), 
                    date("Y-m-d")/*fechafin*/, $payer_email, $plan['plan_precio'], $txn_id, 
                    date("Y-m-d"), $clave, $usuplan_tel_iCassy,$usuario['usuario_telf'], 0);

                $plan = $SQL->obtener_plan_webhook($usuario_id);

                $SQL->crear_historico($plan['usuplan_usuario_id'], $plan['usuplan_plan_id'], 
                $plan['usuplan_plan_nombre'], date("Y-m-d"), date("Y-m-d"),
                $plan['usuplan_PP_IdPerfil'], $plan['usuplan_PP_monto'], $plan['usuplan_PP_IdTransaccion'], 
                'Cancelado', $plan['usuplan_fechareg'], 'cancelado', $plan['usuplan_iCassy_tel'], 
                $plan['usuplan_usuario_tel']);

                $SQL->actualizar_status_usuario_2($plan['usuplan_usuario_id'], 'cancelado');


                $texto = "
                    Sr.(a) ".$usuario['usuario_nombre'].", El proceso cancelación de la suscripción de su Plan se produjo de manera exitosa.
                    <br><br>
                    ";
                    $asunto = "Suspensión de Plan - ICASSY";

                    $libemail->enviarcorreo($usuario['usuario_email'], $asunto, $texto);



                $SQL->actualizar_plan($id, 0);

        }else if ($type === 'subscr_eot'){

                $SQL->registrar_plan($usuario_id, $getplan_id, $plan['plan_nombre'], date("Y-m-d"), 
                    date("Y-m-d")/*fechafin*/, $payer_email, $plan['plan_precio'], $txn_id, 
                    date("Y-m-d"), $clave, $usuplan_tel_iCassy,$usuario['usuario_telf'], 1);

                $plan = $SQL->obtener_plan_webhook($usuario_id);

                $SQL->crear_historico($plan['usuplan_usuario_id'], $plan['usuplan_plan_id'], 
                $plan['usuplan_plan_nombre'], date("Y-m-d"), date("Y-m-d"),
                $plan['usuplan_PP_IdPerfil'], $plan['usuplan_PP_monto'], $plan['usuplan_PP_IdTransaccion'], 
                'Cancelado', $plan['usuplan_fechareg'], 'cancelado', $plan['usuplan_iCassy_tel'], 
                $plan['usuplan_usuario_tel']);

                $SQL->actualizar_status_usuario_2($plan['usuplan_usuario_id'], 'suspendido');

                $texto = "
                    Sr.(a) ".$usuario['usuario_nombre'].", Lastimosamente su Plan fue suspendido por falta de fondos para su recontratación.
                    <br><br>
                    ";
                    $asunto = "Suspensión de Plan - ICASSY";

                    $libemail->enviarcorreo($usuario['usuario_email'], $asunto, $texto);



                $SQL->actualizar_plan($id, 0);
        }
    }
```

**Solo el IPN**

```
 <?php


$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();



foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

$getplan_id=$_REQUEST['id_plan'];
$usuario_id=$_REQUEST['id_usuario'];
// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {



    //  Aqui obtengo las variables después de ejecutarse el pago.
    /*$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];*/
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];

    /*$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];*/
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];





    }
    // <---- HERE you can do your INSERT to the database

    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // log for manual investigation

    }

    $subscr_id = $_POST['subscr_id'];

    if(!empty($subscr_id)){
            $type = $_POST['txn_type'];


    if($type === 'subscr_cancel' ){


        }else if ($type === 'subscr_eot'){




          }
    }
```

**Pero la sección que me falla en mi código es esta**

```
$subscr_id = $_POST['subscr_id'];



if(!empty($subscr_id)){
        $type = $_POST['txn_type'];


if($type === 'subscr_cancel' ){


    }else if ($type === 'subscr_eot'){




      }
}
```

Este código tiene el error que se ejecuta más de una vez es decir en vez de solo obtener una sola cancelación por parte del usuario obtengo 2 o 3 incluso a veces cae otra después de un rato. La lógica es muy simple en esta sección no sé si por esto se produzca tal problema. Simplemente trato de filtrar sólo las notificaciones con un ID de suscripción y un por tipo de operación que en este caso solo son suscripciones canceladas o suspendidas.

Este es todo mi código del IPN soy nuevo usando esta función de Paypal. Gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Hola, no le entiendo a tanto código, ¿podrías resumirlo un poquito más en donde creas que está el error dentro tu script?

Comment: Perfecto amigo no hay problema ya hago el cambio

Comment: porque no creas peque;as funciones o una clase con metodos para cada paso o step! como lo tienes y una simple salida a un archivo log te dira que metodo que se esta ejecutando mas de una vez porque la parte donde esta el error es un simple condicional pude ser que `$usuario['usuario_nombre']` sea un arreglo de datos y por ello este enviado mas de una vez el correo! pero no podria asegurarlo ya que no se como retorna los datos `new SQL;`

Comment: Gracias amigo pero no es un arreglo solo es un único valor.